# Generate email attachment using SharePoint forms and Power Apps

Tags: email, sharepoint, attachment, powerapps

I have a standard SharePoint form that uses Power Apps to customize the form. When the user hits submit on that form it sends an email. Is there a way to create a CSV or Excel file through Power Apps, on button press, that contains all the data within the form that is attached to the email? In this screenshot I'd want to have the email and attachment generated on button press then send the email containing the CM, Name, Date, and Time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create you CSV into Powerapps as String in an variable. But you will need to use Microsoft Automate to create you file and attach into email and send it.